# JSON Object in swift is valid but not by JSON Standards

Tags: swift

I am working with an API that I talk to via my app. When I create normal JSON and POST this to the API everything works fine. But when I create a JSON with a dictionary inside like the following

```
["answer": {
    housenumber = 12;
    housenumberAdditional = "";
    postcode = 1234AB;
}]
```

the object for the "answer" key is not like it should be ["String" : "String"] but instead of the colon there is a =

Even though the way I am creating those is

```
let answers: [String: String] = ["postcode" : postcodeTextField.text!, "housenumber" : housenumber.text!, "housenumberAdditional" : additional.text!]
```

and then I do

```
func someMethod(params: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?) {
  req = NSMutableURLRequest(urlString: "url string")
  req.appendParameters(params!)
// the rest of the request... 
}
```

What is going wrong here? ( I am using [this](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) library for the HTTP requests. )

Comment: That library's `appendParameters` claims to "append the parameters using the standard HTTP Query model". Which means as a query string or a multipart form. There's no JSON implied anywhere in the chain. What step do you think imputes JSON? And where are you getting that text representation from?

Comment: With NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(params) I check if its a valid JSONObject and it always returns true. the text I get is from printing the params like: print("\(params!)")

Comment: Just use AFNetworking or Alamofire.

Comment: @Reshad `isValidJSONObject` just checks that the given object is able to be serialized in JSON... nothing more than that.

Comment: Which version of Swift? How did you produce the JSON text in the question?

Comment: swift 2.0 I got it working now by using the JSONSerializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject`:

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object can be converted to JSON data.

So that indicates that your structure **could** be converted to JSON data.

`print("(params!)"`

> Writes the textual representations of items ... into the standard output.

So nothing "is going wrong here". You've got an object that can be converted to JSON. You've seen a texture representation of the object.

If you want the JSON version of the object, use `NSJSONSerialization`.

As you're using an HTTP library and its `appendParameters`, which seeks to add parameters to an HTTP request via a query string or as a multipart form then (i) you don't want JSON — it's not valid for HTTP parameters; and (ii) even if you did, it wouldn't be your responsibility to generate it.